# store, shop, restaurant, or branch?

Tags: word-choice

When I talk about Subway or Tim Horton's, should I say it is a store, a shop, a restaurant, or a branch? For example,

> XXXX University has both *shops* on campus.

In the above, *both* means Subway and Tim Horton's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shops really implies selling items rather than food, branches (at least in BE) implies banks or shops and it's pushing it call either of them restaurants - I would say outlets.

Comment: +1 because *outlets* is the best word for OP's construction, but I don't think *branches* are that closely tied to **banks** in the UK. Assuming Subway and Tim Horton's have already been specified, I'd be quite happy with *"Both have branches at XXXX University"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - agreed

Comment: Outlets implies items to me as well. Outlets are places where either traditionally catalog companies, or single brands sell their item at their own retail location, rather than a department store. A J.Crew outlet for instance.

Comment: In the UK an outlet is sometimes a trading establishment that sells damaged or out of date goods.

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily I would happily refer to either or both of those as *(fast-food) restaurants*, but in this case the best word might actually be *[franchise](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/franchise)*.

Comment: To be hairsplitting, franchise is a specific commercial arrangement. Both subway and Timmies are franchises but McDs aren't

Comment: @MartinBeckett, not to be hairjoining? but only by one narrow definition is McDonald's not a franchise. In a more general definition, and I think this an appropriate place for semantic debate, the concept of a franchise very neatly covers McDonald's. Otherwise, why would they have a [franchising website](http://www.aboutmcdonalds.com/mcd/franchising.html) or be listed in Entrepreneur as one of the [Top Ten Franchises](http://www.entrepreneur.com/franchise500/index.html) for 2011?

Comment: @sam - apparently some McDs in some regions are franchises but most are direct owned. Starbucks aren't franchises. Generally the more corporate image the chain the less they franchise